# SQL,PHP, multiple tables, recordsets, advise needed

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

Tbl_bands PRI bid
    Tbl_Albums PRI aid
        Tbl_Tracks PRI tid
            Tbl_Tabs PRI tabid

PHP page for a band:
i want to dispay all the albums for this band
under each album i want to display all the tracks of that album
under each track i want to list all the tabs if available assosiated with this track

What way do you recommend to achieve this with php/mysql

Comment: By using joins. https://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=mysql+joins&oq=mysql+joins&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.91.2624.0.2904.15.12.2.1.1.0.149.1195.6j6.12.0...0.0...1c.1.hnMHUB2la5Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e4840b827d8f70fa&bpcl=35243188&biw=1920&bih=935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give you the data you want. Add WHERE clausules where-ever needed and ORDER BY in the order you would like to receive the resultset.

By using LEFT JOINS you'll get also the bands with no albums, or albums without tracks or tracks without tabs.

```
SELECT 
  Tbl_bands.*,
  Tbl_Albums.*,
  Tbl_Tracks.*,
  Tbl_Tabs.*
FROM 
  Tbl_bands
LEFT JOIN 
  Tbl_Albums
ON 
  Tbl_bands.bid = Tbl_Albums.BandId
LEFT JOIN
  Tbl_Tracks 
ON 
  Tbl_Albums.aid = Tbl_Tracks.AlbumId
LEFT JOIN
  Tbl_Tabs
ON
  Tbl_Tracks.tid = Tbl_Tabs.TrackId
WHERE
  // conditions
ORDER BY 
  // columns
LIMIT
  0, 1000
```